# Android-jquerymobile: how to define css for button onclick

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQueryMobile pages inside my Android's `WebView`. For my jQM page buttons, i have css like..

```
jQuery(".pm_btn").css("background-image", "url(bluebutton.png)");

jQuery('.pm_btn').mousedown(function() {
  jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(redbutton.png)";                                    
}).mouseup(function() {
  jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(bluebutton.png)");
});
```

`
On Button onclick, the background images are flipping correctly when I access jQM page from web browser. But this is not working when I accessed the same page from Android's WebView.

Can anybody plz help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
nehatha

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

```
$('.btn').bind("vmousedown", function() {
jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(image1.png)");                                    
}).bind("vmouseup", function() {
$(this).css("background-image", "url(image2.png)");                                 
});
```